# How to process and propagate data to two different type of clients?

Tags: reactjs, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am having the following use case and I am not sure how to approach it.

- A Kafka producer generates data to a topic, lets call the data X
- A Kafka consumer reads them.
- The consumer sends the data to a server for further actions on them (a heavy task), lets say the resulting object is now X1
- I want the server that did the actions, to inform another client (a react client) about the result.

Here are some solutions I have thought about:

Websockets: I need to have a connection initiated by the client (correct me if I am wrong), which is not part of the flow I build.

Long polling to registry-like storage (eg mongo): When a new key has been identified (let's say by insertion date), grab the associated data.

Queueing: The server will put the processed result in a queue (or maybe in another Kafka topic). React will consume that queue. Maybe via a web socket backend endpoint (as connecting Kafka with react doesn't sound good) which will do periodic polling to the queue and will receive the data via the WebSocket.

How do those sound?  Any other ideas are appreciated. My eventual architecture goal is to have a good enough solution that can be implemented relatively fast.

Comment: You can also have a timer that fetch the result from an api every 'time' you want. I prefere Websocket for "real time" and the ease of use.

Comment: So your suggestion is to poll the server every K seconds of I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes why not, depends on what you wait for, and the qty of request or clients. But if you can install some websocket system, It's easy to install and setup mosquitto on the server and have Real Time feedback with pub/sub, this is what I do for my home.

Comment: Thank you, I will do some more research based on your suggestion